# Is it possible to store big integers in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I want to store pretty big integers (30 digits). I can’t store it in [Memgraph](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/data-types) integers which are 64 bit integers, or in floats without losing precision.

Is there a way that I can use to store large integer numbers in Memgraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no way to store such data type in Memgraph, but there is a [GitHub issue for this](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph/issues/829).